# A nicer way of writing a table

Tags: tables, formatting

I was wondering if there's a nicer way to write such a table... Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
 \documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
  \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{slashbox}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|l|lll|}
 \hline
\backslashbox{$f_i$}{$c_j$} & $c_1$ & $c_2$                              &          $c_3$    \\ \hline
 $f_1$  & 2.79 & 3.96                              & 4.76    \\
$f_2$  & 5.46 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.34} & 2.87    \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{ costs $b_{ij}$}\label{t4}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a read of the `booktabs` documentation and follow its recommendations. Although you are loading it, you do not seem to actually use it at all. (If you don't like its suggestions, no point in loading the package ;).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code shows a comparisson between the current code and one produced using [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{slashbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|lll|}
  \hline
  \backslashbox{$f_i$}{$c_j$} & $c_1$ & $c_2$                              &          $c_3$    \\ \hline
  $f_1$  & 2.79 & 3.96                              & 4.76    \\
  $f_2$  & 5.46 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.34} & 2.87    \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{costs $b_{ij}$}
  \label{t4}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=1.2]}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$c_j$} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
  f_i & {$c_1$} & {$c_2$} & {$c_3$}    \\ 
  \cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
  f_1  & 2.79 & 3.96                              & 4.76    \\
  f_2  & 5.46 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1.34} & 2.87    \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{costs $b_{ij}$}
  \label{t4}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

### Some of the improvements

- No vertical rules.
- Above all: no diagonal rules.
- Better "air" for rows.
- Alignment at decimal point in the columns with numerical values through `siunitx`'s features.

Comment: Is `S[table-format=1.2]` the command that issues the alignment? I always used `dcolumn` but this one looks easier to adopt.

Comment: @Alenanno Yes. `table-format` is the shortcut to declare how many figures to reserve for each part of the input. I also use `dcolumn` for this sort of things, but `siunitx` offers more features.